# VirtualBox guest can get out- Windows 7 host can't get in

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Have a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox using NAT. It has an IP of 10.0.2.15. The VM can hit anything in the outside world. However, the host OS (Windows 7) cannot ping the internal VM ('Destination net unreachable').

Any tips on how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use nat, use a bridged interface?

Comment: ARGH man I would if the network I was on allowed it, but thanks for not answering the question.

Comment: @Wells-Zoredache was answering that way because this question has come up a LOT on the Internet, and 99% of the time bridging *is* the answer because of the funky way NAT worked on Virtualbox. Port forwarding was a PAIN and very limited when NATting the interface. In NAT mode, Virtualbox really does isolate the system quite heavily and you're going to have some gymnastics to get it to do anything beyond sharing a directory with the host as a mapped drive.

Comment: @Wells Oliver, I don't use virtualbox and I don't know how to fix the private network to be usable from the host.  I just thought I would double check that you had tried or ruled out the obvious solution based on my experience with other VM products.

Comment: @zoredache-well, your guess neatly dovetails with other advice I've seen on VBox in cases like this. Any time someone wants to test something involving networking from host to VM, it's advised that they use bridging. Unless something has really really changed, accessing the VM behind software NAT is really difficult to get working properly.

Comment: @Zoredache-and my own experiences, too. I had a horrible time with it until I bridged it.

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/110403/connect-to-guest-from-host-virtual-box

Comment: Whenever I couldn't get bridged to work, I always did two networks: Host-only and NAT. Host-only was for talking to the VM from the host or vice-versa, and NAT was for talking to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the VirtualBox manual, a virtual machine with NAT acts like a computer connected to the Internet through a router.  In other words, the virtual machine is in a private network behind the router and cannot be accessed by the host.

If you change the network adapter to "bridged", the host will be able to see your virtual machine.  But, so does everyone else on the same network.  I have tried this with Windows 7 host and Windows 7 guest.  Windows 7 discover each other immediately.

The manual also mentions about port forwarding, but I am still learning from other experts.  Sorry, cannot give any suggestion on this area.

No much real help.  But, hope this give you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is still the solution (not sure if VirtualBox will like that but...) to add another network card. One on NAT for contacting the outside world, and the other sharing a private network with the host. Normally it'll do the trick.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If NAT doesn't work (doesn't surprise me) and you can't use Bridged mode, create a Host-only network.  A Host-only network behaves like a Bridged network, but there is no connection to the physical network.  Essentially it creates a virtual switch and connects the virtual adapters to that.  If you need an adapter on the host system, a Microsoft Loopback Adapter will likely work if VirtualBox doesn't supply virtual host adapters.

If you need to get to the Internet from the guest as well, create an additional network adapter in the guest which uses NAT.

**Be sure *not* to create any virtual or physical networks on the same IP subnet.**  They are separate networks and *must* be configured with different IP subnets or your computer will send data packets to the wrong location!  Your communication will silently fail, as you will have essentially told your computer to turn left when it needed to bear right.

This is trivial to configure on VMWare Workstation with the Virtual Network Editor.  I haven't used VirtualBox since v2, but I can see from [the manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) that this type of configuration is possible.