# Access VirtualBox client (WinXP) from host (Linux) when client is connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, virtualbox, cisco-vpn

I have a host (Ubuntu Linux) with VirtualBox on which is installed client (Windows XP).
I set bridge connection for them.

Host has IP `192.168.0.102` and client `192.168.0.103`.

On client I've installed WAMP server and on host I can access it by simply call `192.168.0.103`.

When I connect on client to the Cisco VPN (need access to database over VPN) I cannot access that server from host.

What should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Cisco VPN?

If it is the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client, then you should enable LAN access in it.

You might not be able to get more than 1 IP address from the VPN though. If that is the case you should use NAT mode, then your virtual machine will have the same network access as your host.

Comment: It's not AnyConnect, but I can enable LAN - however it not helps.
When I tried to set it as NAT, I forwarded ports like posted here http://serverfault.com/questions/110403/connect-to-guest-from-host-virtual-box - it works until I connect to vpn.

Comment: Then your VPN is not allowing you to use up more than 1 IP address, which is fairly normal. You will need to go with the NAT mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at split-tunneling on your VPN which will allow you to access other networks on the local system. [Duplicate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/213179/unable-to-access-lan-when-cisco-client-is-connected)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar configuration.

Don't try the VPN over vboxnet0, what you need is to declare one of the 4 interfaces over eth0 in bridge mode.

It works well with Cisco VPN, running over a XP interface, when the bridge is on eth0.  However when the bridge is over wlan0 : NO WAY.

I think you will find bug reports about this.